# Kentor AuthServices: TokenLifetime and Expiration claim

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, kentor-authservices

How is TokenLifetime is handled in Kentor AuthServices (SP initiated SSO)? I assumed it has to be handled differently than WebSSOLifetime.

- Does SP require to have claim: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/expiration from IDP (ADFS)?
- Does Kentor AuthServices handles expiration claim from IDP?

Thank you for your help.